# How to share via Facebook or Twitter without edit-message view via UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, twitter, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` to sharing messages from my app via Facebook or Twitter. I want to share message without changing content of this message. When I'm using `UIActivityViewController` after select type of sharing e.g. Twitter then iOS shows to me 'twitter-view' where i can edit message. I don't want to to this. I'm trying to show only types of sharing options and after one is selected, share. It is possible to do with `UIActivityViewController`? If not, how can I do this correclty?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I used `Accounts` framework to do this.

Answer (score 0):

use OAuth may be a little complicate, but you can do any thing you want with Twitter or Facebook OAuth API

https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk